# How to Send a structure using sendto()

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, multicast, sendto

I have created structure :

```
struct buffer
{
    string ProjectName ;
    string ProjectID ;
}

buffer buf;
buf.ProjectID = "212";
buf.ProjectName = "MyProj";
```

Now to send this structure using sendto method , I am typecasting the strucure and sending it back as below:

```
char *sendbuf = (char*)&buf;
sentbytes = sendto(sock,sendbuf,strlen(sendbuf),0,(sockaddr*)&their_addr,sizeof(their_addr));
```

But while I am casting my Struct ti `char*` the actual data is loosing it's values and while debugging I see sendbuf is containing some other values.

Can some one let me know how can I send the above structure using sendto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the structure using POD, the string is not something you can use in that way. Instead you need to declare it something like

```
struct buffer
{
  char ProjectName[MAX_LENGTH_PROJECT_NAME+1];
  char ProjectID[MAX_LENGTH_PROJECT_ID+1];
};
```

EDIT: clarification, the string contains a pointer to a heap allocated memory block, so you are not actually sending the characters when you try to send that structure.

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` holds its data in dynamically allocated memory. You could send separately each string and length of a string which you can get by using `std::string::c_str` and `std::string::size`.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer using marshall/unmarshall when sending data over network. A C++-style is to use "<< / >>" for streaming to a sendable buffer.  This way, you have more control over what you are sending and how it is sent (binary,text,xml,...).  Boost also has a [serialization module](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization).