# error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'char [5]' to 'char [20]'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct

This is linked to my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606933/how-to-send-a-structure-using-sendto)

Wher I created a Struct :

```
struct buffer
{
    char ProjectName[20];
       char ProjectID[20];
};
```

Now while I am trying to assign values to it:

```
buffer buf;
buf.ProjectID = "3174";
buf.ProjectName = "NDS";
```

I am getting this error:

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'char [5]' to 'char [20]'
```

and to resolve this I tried decreasing the size of  structure as below(must not be the way to do it) :

```
struct buffer
{

    char ProjectName[4];
    char ProjectID[5];
};
```

and the get `error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value`

Comment: Use std::String rather that char arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to copy the string into the array:

```
strcpy(buf.ProjectName, "3174");
```

Be careful with the length of the strings being copied into the arrays

Answer (score 4):

You can not assign strings like that in C++. You need to use the function such as `strcpy` to copy the string. Or better still use the class `std::string`

Comment: @Subhen See response by @jab for an example of using strcpy()

Answer (score 3):

That's normal, you can't really assign values to char tables that way (there are numerous different solutions, sprintf or strcpy for instance). But this is a C problem, not C++.

Since you're coding in C++, you should use std::string to manage your strings (and the c_str() method if you need those strings converted in char tables).

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the first case:

```
buffer buf; 
buf.ProjectID = "3174"; 
buf.ProjectName = "NDS";
```

> $2.13.4/1 - "An ordinary string
>   literal has type “array of n const
>   char” and static storage duration
>   (3.7)"

The type of `"3174"` is `char const [5]` and type of "NDS" is `char const [4]`. While trying to attempt the assignment to `'buf.ProjectID'`, the compiler has to essentially convert from `'char const [5]'` to `'char const [20]'`. This conversion is not allowed by C++ rules. In fact, a more appropriate error message is thrown in your next attempt.

> $8.3.4/5 - '[Note: conversions
>   affecting lvalues of array type are
>   described in 4.2. Objects of array
>   types **cannot be modified**, see 3.10. ]".

In other words it means, that name of an array is non modifiable lvalue (which is what the 2nd compiler message says).

> $5.17- "There are several assignment
>   operators, all of which group
>   right-to-left. All require a
>   **modifiable lvalue** as their left
>   operand, and the type of an assignment
>   expression is that of its left
>   operand."

So here is the summary:

For the assignment expression to work, the left hand side should be a modifiable LValue expression. However an array is a non modifiable Lvalue expression. Hence it can not be assigned to.

Comment: There's no way the poster's going to understand that... :-/.

Comment: @Tony: Thanks for that feedback. Have slightly elaborated it further

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that C++ is a bit unintuitive here.  You can say:

```
char name[10] = "abcd";
```

and, given your definition above:

```
buffer buf = { "NDS", "3174" };
```

The latter relies on a one-to-one correspondence between fields in the structure and values in the list, so I've had to reverse the order used in your assignments.

But, you can't do your

```
buf.ProjectName = "abcde";
```

What that actually requests in C++ is that buf.ProjectName be loaded with a pointer to memory containing the character data "abcde".  You can't do that though, as ProjectName itself is another buffer for character data, and not of pointer-to-character-data.

So, when you have a source and destination area containing NUL-terminated strings (Google ASCIIZ if necessary), you need to use a support function to copy from one to the other:

```
strcpy(buf.ProjectName, "name");
```

If ProjectName's dimension is too small, then your string may overwrite memory that the compiler hasn't reserved for ProjectName, probably causing a crash or erroneous output.  You can protect against this - if the relative sizes of the strings isn't obviously ok - using `strncpy(buf.ProjectName, "name", sizeof buf.ProjectName)`.  Unfortunately, this means `buf.ProjectName` may not hold the full expected value, making it of dubious use.

C++ improves over this way of handling textual data - which is inherited from C - with the std::string class.  You can simple do this:

```
#include <string>
struct Buffer
{
    std::string project_name_;
    std::string project_id_;
};
Buffer b;
b.project_name_ = "abcde"; // works with string literals.
b.project_id_ = b.project_name_;  // can copy from std::string to std::string
```